# Is null equal to null in Oracle database?

Tags: sql, oracle, indexing

I was trying to enforce only one active phone per client using a unique index in Oracle but can't make it work. This works flawlessly in PostgreSQL and DB2 but doesn't seem to work in Oracle.

Here's the example:

```
create table phone (
  client_id number(6) not null,
  active number(1) not null check (active in (0, 1)),
  value varchar2(15)
);

insert into phone (client_id, active, value) values (10, 0, '1111');
insert into phone (client_id, active, value) values (10, 1, '3333');
insert into phone (client_id, active, value) values (15, 0, '5555');
insert into phone (client_id, active, value) values (15, 1, '6666');
insert into phone (client_id, active, value) values (15, 0, '7777'); -- offending row
```

When I try to create the index:

```
create unique index ix1 on phone (client_id, case when active = 1 then active end);
```

It seems that Oracle doesn't like it because a duplicate index entry:

> Error: ORA-01452: cannot CREATE UNIQUE INDEX; duplicate keys found
> SQLState:  72000

If I remove the offending data row, the index can be created.

Comment: Your index has a `case` with no `else`. Is Oracle assigned a 0 to the result of the `case` when it's not 1? It seems that when the row isn't active, it'll be `0`, resulting in two rows with a (15, 0). The title of your question asks about NULL, but I don't see NULL coming into the equation here(?).

Comment: I'd expect `on phone (case when active=1 then client_id end)` to work across database engines.  I don't have time to verify that and write up an answer right now but will try to do so later if no one beats me to it.

Comment: @HardCode - the default `else` value is `null` (not only in Oracle but, I believe, in the SQL Standard). So the OP's attempt was fine from that point of view. The issue was different - it's what MT0 explained in his answer.

Comment: `null` is never equal to `null`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use:

```sql
create unique index ix1 on phone (case active when 1 then client_id end);
```

*sqlfiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/e8702)*

A `UNIQUE` index will not store rows when **all** the columns are `NULL`; however, in your case, the function-based index results in one-of-two values being `NULL` so the row will be indexed and this will cause a duplicate value in the index.

Changing it so that the output is a single value derived from both the `active` and `client_id` columns means that the rows where `active = 0` will result in a `NULL` output from the `CASE` expression and those rows will not be included in the index and only the active rows will be checked for duplicates.

From the Oracle [Unique constraint documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/sqlrf/constraint.html#GUID-1055EA97-BA6F-4764-A15F-1024FD5B6DFE):

> To satisfy a unique constraint, no two rows in the table can have the same value for the unique key. However, the unique key made up of a single column can contain nulls. To satisfy a composite unique key, no two rows in the table or view can have the same combination of values in the key columns. Any row that contains nulls in all key columns automatically satisfies the constraint. However, two rows that contain nulls for one or more key columns and the same combination of values for the other key columns violate the constraint.

Comment: You are so right. Thank you. I should have implemented as a partial index (as you mention).

Comment: However it still bothers me "...will cause a duplicate value in the index...". Well a `(15, null)` is not supposed to be equal to another `(15, null)`. PostgreSQL seems to behave correctly: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/815f55. However, DB2 behaves the same way as Oracle: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=db2_11.1&fiddle=12809e8de8c60f1a9b018aea9c16ce24

Comment: @TheImpaler - In Oracle, `null` is sometimes equal to `null`. When you group by a column, all the rows where that column is `null` are grouped together. If you select distinct <something>, you will get a single `null` in the output even if the <something> is `null` more than once. Similarly, in determining "unique", `null` is equal to itself across rows. You don't see this when the index (or condition) is on a *single* column, because Oracle chose - for whatever reason - to exclude `null` from consideration altogether.

Comment: @TheImpaler Added a link to the Oracle documentation.